# Dynamically change size of objects without affecting other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I understand that the title may be a little confusing (I do not know how else to ask the question) so here is the example I am working on.

http://beautifulcreationphotography.net/gallery.html

So my issue is that whenever you hover over an image, the other images move around when the image enlarges. One possible solution is to use absolute positioning, but it is such a hassle manually positioning all the images in a grid (I'm looking to make it a grid 3 columns wide).

What are other solutions that would help with this? I'm open to both pure javascript solutions as well as using JS Libraries.

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/pfuRppdY

JS:
http://pastebin.com/9m7TwNXU

CSS:

```
#gallery {
    display:inline;
    margin:50px;
    height:300px;
}

#gallery img {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ever considered using javascript frameworks, like jQuery?

You might wanna check this site: http://codecanyon.net/item/image-effects-pack-jquery-powered/full_screen_preview/136861?ref=lvraa&ref=lvraa&clickthrough_id=60503324&redirect_back=true

Scroll to the zoom effect and you will see what you're looking for.

Comment: While this is what I am looking for, I would prefer it to be free and open source. Thank you for the suggestion though. I will also browse the jQuery library more closely for something that may suit my situation. If there are any other solutions, please continue to post them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Give each image a different z-index!  That way they are all in different planes...

You could do this with JavaScript/DHTML methods.  If you number your images in an array, it would be easy to loop through the images and assign an increasing z-index to each image.

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work. I updated the page at the link above, so if you wouldn't mind take a look at the code and make sure I didn't do anything wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about putting the images in a table?  Give each cell 33.3% width and give the image an initial width of say 70% and onmouseover expand to 100%?

Comment: From my understanding, using tables to format is bad programming. I am all for doing what is easiest, but I would like to avoid tables as it is more difficult to keep it maintenanced.